# IMFMediaEngine duplicate player surface

Tags: winapi, video-player, windows-media-player

How to use IMFMediaEngine for playing one video simultaneously in two areas or windows?

The IMFMediaEngineClassFactory::CreateInstance method has frame server mode and rendering mode. The rendering mode creates single video output provided by Window HWND or DirectComposition

Does it mean that I need to use frame server mode? And how to do that for making two outputs? Also I need async output, for video won't be interrupted by main thread.

Comment: There are examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-store-app-using-wrl-and-media-foundation?view=msvc-160

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I edited the question, limited it to IMFMediaEngine part